# it must be scrupulousess run mad

Tags: grammar

The following quote is from "Mansfield Park" by Jane Austen:

> Their mother had no objection to the plan, and they were not in the
> least afraid of their father's disapprobation. There could be no harm
> in what had been done in so many respectable families, and by so many
> women of the first consideration; it must be scrupulousness **run
> mad**, **that** could see anything to censure in a plan like theirs,
> comprehending only brothers and sisters, intimate friends, and which
> would never be heard of beyond themselves.

My question is: I wonder if there is an ellipsis of a relative pronoun in between "scrupulousness" and "run mad". This sentence will read:"It must be scrupulousness THAT has run mad. And another thing,
what does "that" refer back to?

Answer (score 3):

You can understand it like that, but English does not require a relative pronoun in that position

> It is chicken cooked perfectly.

The participle phrase "cooked perfectly" describes the chicken, just as "run mad" (which was one of Austen's favourite collocations) describes the "scrupulousness"

"Run mad", means "continued to an absurd degree".

The "that" which follows refers to "scrupulousness run mad", or by extension a person who practices scrupulousness to that degree.  But the style is "flighty" and rather 18th century, rather than how a modern person would speak or write.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  And can you tell me what "that" here in bold refers back to?  Does it refer to "scrupulousness run mad"?

Comment: Sorry, I mean the word "that" in bold, which follows immediately the word "mad".

Answer (score 0):

A modern version of this is the phrase  ["political correctness gone mad"](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%22political%20correctness%20gone%20mad%22&atb=v245-1&ia=web)

The idea is that the modern tendency of people to be politically correct or to advocate political correctness has become excessive almost to the point of insanity.

---

Note: I make no judgement on this. I am merely relating the meaning of the phrase.